# How to remove the list bracket in some expression?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two problems with the List bracket `{}`.

First, I want to get a  specific component of `LeviCivitaTensor`, so I should use

```
Normal[ LeviCivitaTensor[n] ] [[ i1, i2, i3, ..., in ]]
```

For other purpose, however, I need to use

```
Normal[ LeviCitaTensor[n] ] [[ Table[ i[j], {j, 1, n}] ]]
```

However, the `Table` gives an additional `List` bracket "{}", and my method won't work.

Second, I want to calculate

```
Sum[f, {i[1], 1, n}, {i[2], 1, n}, ..., {i[m], 1, n}]
```

However, `m` in my function is an input, so I use `Sum[f, Table[{i[j], 1, n}, {j, 1, m}]]`. But the `Table` once again gives rise to an additional `List` bracket which make my code unworkable.

Can some one help me out? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have a look at [Flatten](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html?q=Flatten).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Still can't get rid of the {}

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, try adding `Sequence@@` in front of your `Table` expression.

Comment: it works. thanks. but need to evaluate first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should know that you don't need `Normal` to index the `LeviCivitaTensor`:

```
LeviCivitaTensor[3][[1, 2, 3]]
(* 1 *)
```

Now to your first problem. This can be solved with `Apply` (shorthand form `@@`):

```
i[1] = 1; (* example i data *)
i[2] = 2;
i[3] = 3;

LeviCivitaTensor[3][[##]] & @@ Table[i[j], {j, 1, 3}]
(* 1 *)
```

The second problem can be solved similarly. Alternatively, `Sequence` is an option:

```
ClearAll[i]

n = 2;
m = 3;

Sum[f, Sequence @@ Table[{i[j], 1, n}, {j, 1, m}] // Evaluate]

Sum[f, ##] & @@ Table[{i[j], 1, n}, {j, 1, m}]

(* 8 f *)
(* 8 f *)
```

Comment: Oh man you are great, thanks a lot.